# Using Input Field to occupy Output Field through Extensions Class

Tags: controller, extension

M a SF rookie and i need the output fields ie Amount,Price and Quantity to be displayed when their respective Product is selected.All are fields of an Sobject known as Sales_Order_Line_Item__c.The First page block section uses the standard controller

[VF]

```
<apex:page standardController="Sales_Order__c" extensions="SalesOrderExtension" tabStyle="Sales_Order__c">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Sales Order"/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Sales_Order__c.Customer__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Sales_Order__c.Price_Book__c}" />
                <!--
                create additional fields: invoice date, due date, status picklist (pending, payment received, delivered, cancelled)
                -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Total Amount</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputLabel id="lblTotalAmount">0</apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Order" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Line Item" action="{!AddLineItem}" immediate="true" reRender="pbtLineItems"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!LineItems}" var="lineItem" id="pbtLineItems">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product"><apex:inputField value="{!lineItem.Product__c}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price"><apex:inputField  value="{!lineItem.Unit_Price__c}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity"><apex:inputField  value="{!lineItem.Quantity__c}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount"><apex:inputField  value="{!lineItem.Amount__c}"/></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[EXTENSION]

```
public class SalesOrderExtension {
    public Apexpages.StandardController StanCon { get; set; }
    public List<Sales_Order_Line_Item__c> LineItems { get; set; }

    public SalesOrderExtension(Apexpages.StandardController con){
        this.StanCon = con;
        Init();
    }

    private void Init(){
        LineItems = new List<Sales_Order_Line_Item__c>();
        LineItems.add(new Sales_Order_Line_Item__c());
    }

    public void AddLineItem(){
        LineItems.add(new Sales_Order_Line_Item__c());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapper class to show value of selected product.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class